# Enable USB debugging in Android via PC

Tags: android, debugging, usb, fastboot

I only have access to fastboot/recovery mode (due to software error) of my android device and i want to enable usb debugging through pc so that i can reinstall the Software. How can i do that? is there any way like using android studio?

Comment: Android Studio is used for development, not to install SO or ROOMS on devices.  You could do it through Android Debug Bridge (ADB)  included in the Android SDK development kit

Comment: You can't use something that requires USB debugging to enable USB debugging.

Comment: Try looking at [How to Enable USB Debugging from PC Using USB Command?](https://itoolab.com/unlock-android/enable-usb-debugging-from-pc/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=704541C633954E1FA032524F6B233DFD)